# How to use morphable multiple select that related together(like choose two category and then choose some sub category of them) In Subfields?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a problem to use morphable related selects in subfields of laravel backpack. Actually, How can I use this code in backpack subfields?

```
        CRUD::field('colorable')
            ->label(trans('translate.to'))
            ->addMorphOption('App\Models\PlexiColor', trans("translate.plexi_color"), [
                'type'                    => 'select2_from_ajax',
                'attribute'               => "name",
                'entity'                  => 'colorable',
                'model'                   => "App\Models\PlexiColor",
                'data_source'             => backpack_url('board-color-price/fetch/plexi-color'),
                'minimum_input_length'    => 0,
                'method'                  => 'POST',
                'include_all_form_fields' => true,
            ])
            ->addMorphOption('App\Models\MultiStyleColor', trans("translate.multistyle_colors"), [
                'type'                    => 'select2_from_ajax',
                'attribute'               => "name",
                'entity'                  => 'colorable',
                'model'                   => "App\Models\MultiStyleColor",
                'data_source'             => backpack_url('board-color-price/fetch/multistyle-color'),
                'minimum_input_length'    => 0,
                'method'                  => 'POST',
                'include_all_form_fields' => true,
            ])
            ->addMorphOption('App\Models\StealColor', trans("translate.steal_colors"), [
                'type'                    => 'select2_from_ajax',
                'attribute'               => "name",
                'entity'                  => 'colorable',
                'model'                   => "App\Models\StealColor",
                'data_source'             => backpack_url('board-color-price/fetch/steal-color'),
                'minimum_input_length'    => 0,
                'method'                  => 'POST',
                'include_all_form_fields' => true,
            ])
            ->addMorphOption('App\Models\PleximirrorColor', trans("translate.Pleximirror_colors"), [
                'type'                    => 'select2_from_ajax',
                'attribute'               => "name",
                'entity'                  => 'colorable',
                'model'                   => "App\Models\PleximirrorColor",
                'data_source'             => backpack_url('board-color-price/fetch/pleximirror-colors'),
                'minimum_input_length'    => 0,
                'method'                  => 'POST',
                'include_all_form_fields' => true,
            ])
            ->morphTypeField(['wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6']])
            ->morphIdField(['wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'], 'placeholder' => trans('translate.choose'),]);
```

I did many things but it doesn't work! for example: I use addMorphOption like array in subfield but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, morph fields cannot currently be used as subfields - as of Backpack v5. We recommend you split up this form into multiple forms. You can easily allow the admin to create a related entry in a different form, in a modal, by using the InlineCreate operation - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#create-related-entries-in-a-modal-using-the-inlinecreate-operati